Docker container unable to access nfs volume during boot
(This is my first venture into docker, and I have about a year of home use Ubuntu experience.)
I have a docker volume that mounts a nfs volume from my NAS.
(I manually changed hostname, volume name, container name, etc in these examples to simplify)
$ docker inspect NAS_Data
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2024-09-13T08:24:51-05:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "dockerconfig",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.29.2",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "NAS_Data"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/NAS_Data/_data",
        "Name": "NAS_Data",
        "Options": {
            "device": ":/Data",
            "o": "addr=nfshost.mylocal,nfsvers=4.1",
            "type": "nfs"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }

That volume works as expected when the system is up and running, but not during a boot.
After a system reboot the containers that user that volume do not automatically start.
$ docker inspect *container_name*
[
    {
        "Id": "fa65a6a5645e89235becdffffe2d30e32bf55ad1e0f50e39b5fb61dd8fa30e44",
        "Created": "2024-09-13T13:24:51.12645092Z",
        "Path": "/init",
        "Args": [],
        "State": {
            "**Status": "exited"**,
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 128,
            "**Error": "error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/NAS_Data/_data': error resolving passed in network volume address: lookup nfshost.mylocal on 127.0.0.53:53: server misbehaving**",
            "StartedAt": "2024-09-13T14:07:32.568955099Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2024-09-13T14:07:52.562014425Z"
        },

$ systemctl status docker.service
Sep 13 09:31:28 mediaserver dockerd[3206]: time="2024-09-13T09:31:28.178808335-05:00" level=info msg="No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers

Sep 13 09:31:28 mediaserver dockerd[3206]: time="2024-09-13T09:31:28.409961659-05:00" level=error msg="failed to start container" container=xxxx error="error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/NAS_PlexData/_data': error resolving passed in network volume address: lookup nfshost.mylocal on 127.0.0.53:53:server misbehaving"

Immediately after logging in, I can manually start the containers (no other changes).
$ docker start container_name
the container starts and operates fine accessing the nfs volume.
So, I am assuming the issues is the timing of starting the docker service and the network services.  To try to work around that, I looked at the systemctl status *.target and found that multi-user.target is late in the boot process.  So I modified /lib/systemd/system/docker.service to add "after: multi-user.target" to change the sequencing of when the docker service is started.  It is not import for any of my docker services to be early in the boot process.  I know multi-user.target is not a great choice, but it was last, so I picked it.
I have confirmed that docker.service is starting after multi-user.target is met:
$ systemctl status multi-user.target
● multi-user.target - Multi-User System
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target; static)
     Active: active since Fri 2024-09-13 09:31:26 CDT; 36min ago
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

and from the docker.service error messages, you can see those occur two seconds after multi-user.target is active.  Other services like network nss-lookup, nfs-client, network-online.target all are active before multi-user.target by a couple of seconds.
Since immediately after a reboot I can login and start the docker containers, I feel like my problem is timing in the boot process.  I have tried using IP address vs FQDN host name, but that did not resolve the issue.
When I use IP address vs FQDN the error changes:
$ docker inspect NAS_Data
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2024-09-13T10:53:21-05:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "dockerconfig",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.29.2",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "NAS_Data"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/NAS_Data/_data",
        "Name": "NAS_Data",
        "Options": {
            "device": ":/Data",
            "o": "addr=192.168.x.y,nfsvers=4.1,rw",
            "type": "nfs"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }

$ docker inspect container_name
[
    {
        "Id": "dfb6a0f8c8f8cf59c2e760c65df4712cde53cb72471fe8e011d1c98dc28bb437",
        "Created": "2024-09-13T15:53:21.468039823Z",
        "Path": "/init",
        "Args": [],
        "State": {
            "Status": "exited",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 128,
            "Error": "error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/NAS_Data/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount :/Data:/var/lib/docker/volumes/NAS_Data/_data, data: addr=192.168.x.y,nfsvers=4.1: no route to host",
            "StartedAt": "2024-09-13T15:53:21.79182452Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2024-09-13T15:53:47.693869079Z"
        },

But even using IP address, after a reboot the service starts fine with:
$ docker start container_name
The services accessing the nfs volume are configured using compose.yml and have the property:
restart: unless-stopped
I have tried
restart: on-failure:10
that did not work either.
What do I need to do in order to use the NFS volumes during the boot process?

This appears to be a race condition inside of docker.service.  I was able to delay the start of the service using the docker compose function "Depends_on:". That was able to delay the start of the service.  But it did not delay the creation of the container.  The container errored at system boot because it was not able to mount the NFS share, mainly because the docker service was still starting the network inside of the container.  The error message varied, but was always about network connectivity issues.
I am providing my work-around that solved my problem. I would really like to find a way to mount the volume inside of docker compose, but I don't think it can be done with functionality available today.  Maybe on a slower computer it would work, but not on my PC.
I deleted the nfs volumes from the "volumes:" portion of the docker compose file.  Shown here by commenting them out:
volumes:
#  NAS_PlexData:
#    driver: local
#    name: NAS_PlexData
#    driver_opts:
#      type: nfs
#      o: addr=192.168.x.x,nfsvers=4.1,rw
#      device: :/PlexData

Then I removed the volume (once all the containers accessing it were stopped):
$ docker volume rm NAS_PlexData

I modified the docker compose file to specify the same NFS volume via the Ubuntu mount point instead of using NFS inside of docker.
Here is the resulting compose file.  I intentionally left the commented out items I had tried to resolve this in other ways that did not work.
  sonarr:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/sonarr:latest
    container_name: sonarr
#    depends_on:
#      watchtower:
#        condition: service_healthy
#        restart: true
#        required: true
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=US/Central
    volumes:
      - /mnt/MediaRaid/DockerConfig/config_sonarr:/config
      - /mnt/NAS-Plex:/NAS_MediaContent
#      - NAS_PlexData:/NAS_MediaContent
    ports:
       - 8989:8989
    restart: unless-stopped
#    restart: on-failure:10

